# Dropdown do Semantic UI não funciona com o AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou utilizando o Framework Semantic UI, quando o recurso *dropdown* está dentro da diretiva *ng-repeat*, este recurso simplesmente para de funcionar.

Alguém já passou por isso ou algo parecido?

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja relacionado ao fato do `ng-repeat` gerar os elementos dinamicamente, e o tal framework que você citou deve fazer o _bind_ dos componente no `onload` da pagina. Mas para podermos lhe dar uma resposta com maior clareza, recomendo que crie um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Fernando, consegui resolver. Criei uma diretiva no angular para poder fazer o dropdown funcionar.